# How do you formally verify that there are "No arithmetic or other exceptions"?

Tags: formal-verification

seL4 is a formally verified operating system. In this [pdf](http://ts.data61.csiro.au/publications/nicta_full_text/3783.pdf) it says there is "No arithmetic or other exceptions". How does one verify that? Is the implementation brute forcing every valid input?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not brute-force!

Lots of different techniques have been tried to establish arithmetic safety with varying degrees of success. Most computer arithmetic is fully formalized these days, both in formalisms such as Isabelle/HOL, Coq, ACL2, and many other theorem provers; and also in more automated techniques like SMT solving. In these systems, you get a model of your system (either written by hand or automatically extracted from actual source code), and then you prove that there are no paths in your execution that encounter an over/under-flow. Of course, this is easier said than done; but tool support has been steadily getting better over time.

A great paper to look at to see how arithmetic overflow/underflow can be more or less automatically detected is Nikolaj's work within the SMT domain: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/z3prefix.pdf The references contained in there can also be a great starting point to look at other research along these lines.